# How to set up the event Datagridviewcombobox cell selectionchanged?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a DataGridViewComboBoxCell control with some items into it. I would like to get the values when user chooses a value from the dropdown. I cant use DataGridViewComboBoxColumn where EditingControlShowing can be used. I need similar event handler for DataGridViewComboBoxCell. Can anyone help pls.

Please find code sample below:

```
private DataGridViewComboBoxCell NameDropDown = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();     

public void SetDropDown(int index)
      {
         NameDropDown = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();         
         DropDownValues(index);
         for (int j = 0; j < DropDownOld.Items.Count; j++)
         {
            NameDropDown.Items.Add(DropDownOld.Items[j]);
         }
         dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4] = NameDropDown;
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you **can** use the `EditingControlShowing` event to get a handle to the combobox.

Then hook up an event handler for the `SelectedIndexChanged` or whatever event you want and code it..!

```
DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl cbec = null;

private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
                           DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)
    {
        cbec = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
        cbec.SelectedIndexChanged -=Cbec_SelectedIndexChanged;
        cbec.SelectedIndexChanged +=Cbec_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }
}

private void Cbec_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbec != null) Console.WriteLine(cbec.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```